# Avoiding Race Condition in ReactJS with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, race-condition, redux-thunk

I ned some direction from the community as to how to prevent race-condition in ReactJS w/ Redux.

Supposedly two people are looking at the same record, and both would like to make change to it, what is the action flow suppose to look like? I am not sure how to google this query so i decided to ask the community to point me in the right direction.

Initially I thought that if i do a setState and persist it into DB, it will automatically refresh in the eyes of the other users (although I cannot confirm that), otherwise how would I lock the item for change so that other users cannot manipulate the value?

Comment: there is a post about how google might accomplish this in google docs
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092669/how-does-google-docs-deal-with-editing-collisions

Answer (score 1):

You can use websockets along with react redux for this. If `user A` is looking at a record, send a message to server to lock the record. Then broadcast a `locked` message via websocket to other subscribed users who are currently vieweing it. Once the users receive the `locked` websocket message, update react/redux state to show appropriate status.

And as for the race-condition, it could happen and needs to be handled at the server according to the use case. For example, if `user A`'s request reaches first and `User B`'s reach second and if you want to give preference to the first user, lock the resource record, but set the access `true` only for `User A`. Once the `user A` stops editing, remove the lock.

If you want to make the websocket message watching part a separate concern outside the react component, you can look into the redux middleware [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/).